# JSON string to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert a JSON string to pandasdataframe, that looks like this:
I have tried to use pd.read_json(header)
But I get the following error
Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)

I tried a few things with json load. But i don't quite understand the difference between updating a json file and a json string.
Any hints on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you post a sample of the JSON ?

Comment: Make sure to validate your JSON data using a linter such as https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: {"":{"device ID": "","comments": " 20 min slow jog + 10 min rest + 25min all effort run + recovery run and rest ","keywords": "Belt, run","firmware version": "0.6.3","device": "FieldWiz + Belt","sampling rate": 250,"resolution": [16-bit],"date": "2020-05-10","column": ["A1","ECG"],"sensor": ["RAW, ECG"],"label": ["ECG"]}}

I posted a image, but I guess it didn't upload.
The [16-bit] was not "[16-bit]"..
Thanks @JQadrad, it was really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{"":{"device ID": "","comments": " 20 min slow jog + 10 min rest + 25min all effort run + recovery run and rest ","keywords": "Belt, run","firmware version": "0.6.3","device": "FieldWiz + Belt","sampling rate": 250,"resolution": [16-bit],"date": "2020-05-10","column": ["A1","ECG"],"sensor": ["RAW, ECG"],"label": ["ECG"]}} I posted a image, but I guess it didn't upload. The [16-bit] was not "[16-bit]".. Thanks @JQadrad, it was really useful!

As @JQadrad pointed out, I understood the mistake on the json using [enter link description here][1]: http://jsonlint.com